# Cannot get reproducible results with ImageDataGenerator in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to get reproducible results between multiple runs of the same script in keras, but I get different ones at each iteration. My code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed
import random as rn
import os

seed_num = 1
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
np.random.seed(seed_num)
rn.seed(seed_num)

import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)

import tensorflow.keras as ks
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

...some imports...
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


.... data loading etc ....

generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                width_shift_range=0.1,
                height_shift_range=0.1,
                horizontal_flip=True)
                      
generator.fit(X_train, seed=seed_num)                
my_model.fit(generator.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, seed=seed_num), validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=callbacks , epochs=epochs, shuffle=False)
```

I identified the problem to be in `ImageDataGenerator`, i.e., when setting `generator = ImageDataGenerator()` without any augmentation the results are reproducible. I am also running on CPU and TensorFlow version is 2.4.1. What am I missing here?

Comment: The reason why it's not reproducible is because the augmentations within ImageDataGenerator are randomly applied to each image

Comment: @theastronomist so there is no way to make them reproducible? I mean, shouldn't the random augmentations be deterministic if the random seed is fixed?

Comment: @Kate, Is your issue resolved now?Else, can you share complete standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using GPU while creating augmented images can produce nondeterministic results.

To get reproducible results using **ImageDataGenerator** and **GPU**, one way is the following:

```
import random, os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def set_seed(seed=0):
  np.random.seed(seed) 
  tf.random.set_seed(seed) 
  random.seed(seed)
  os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = "1"
  os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISM'] = "1"
  os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)

set_seed()
```

Before `model.fit()` call again `set_seed()`:

```
    set_seed()
    model.fit(...)
```

Otherwise, you can install the package **tensorflow-determinism**:

`pip install tensorflow-determinism`

**If you're using Google Colab, restart your runtime or it won't probably work**

The package will interact with GPU to produce deterministic results.

```
import random, os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def set_seed(seed=0):
  os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
  random.seed(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)
  tf.random.set_seed(seed)

set_seed()

# code
```

Also in this case, before `model.fit()` call again `set_seed()`:

```
    set_seed()
    model.fit(...)
```